# Firebase INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: removeWrite called with nonexistent writeId

Tags: firebase

I'm using a cronJob to start a firebase cloud function.

Everything works but im getting this error:

> Firebase Database (4.2.1) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: removeWrite called
>   with nonexistent writeId

from firebase and the cronJob is returning

> Error: could not handle the request

I think [this person](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/7UAUYgH1UW4/8HyUs-ARAAAJ) had the same issue but I'm not sure how to check if there are 2 functions occurring at the same time, or how to fix it if there are.

Anyone encounter this before or have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. I also had this issue and it says that u are trying to do transaction while removing the ref. In other words my code was like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
this.ref.child('name').transaction(data => { return null }); // or any update
}, 500);

// somewhere later...
this.ref.child('name').remove();
```

In my case, I tried to remove the ref by transaction and by calling remove() method.
I assume firebase cant handle removing ref while transaction is running on this ref.
The solution I did:

```
let isTimeoutStarted: boolean = false;
setTimeout(() => {
isTimeoutStarted = true;
this.ref.child('name').transaction(data => { return null }); // or any update
}, 500);

if(!isTimeoutStarted) {
   this.ref.child('name').remove();
}
```